# Why does my Pendulum keep on accelerating instead of oscillating at the same rate?

Tags: visual-c++

I am trying to simulate a pendulum and it should oscillate between two max points when without any damping applied, but instead it keeps on accelerating.

I have tried changing the value of g to a lower value, I have tried down-scaling the acceleration value or A (which is essentially the same thing).

EDIT:
theta: the current angle in radians.
v = velocity of the pendulum at a time t.
x : x position of the bob of the pendulum.
y : y position of the pendulum.
r : length of the string.
g : constant gravitational pull.
a : acceleration.

```cpp
    while (true)
        {

            theta += v;
            x = r * sin(theta);
            y = r * cos(theta);
            v += a;
            a = -(g/r) * sin(theta);

        }
```

Comment: It's unclear what variables you are using.

Comment: My guess is, your time tick is too coarse (each iteration of the loop models one second), and the error keeps accumulating. Try throwing a sufficiently small delta-time in there: `v += a*dt; theta += v*dt;` The smaller `dt`, the more accurate the computation (but the longer it'll take to model a given period of time).